# Unable to update kafka cluster version in AWS MSK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

We have written python code to upgrade kafka version in AWS MSK and its giving error

```
    ..................................................
    vaibhavkanchan@vkmacbook python-code % ./update_kafka_version.py /gpn-prime/dev/msk/kafka-cluster 2.6.1
    ..................................................
    Cluster ARN: arn:aws:kafka:ap-south-1:xxxx:cluster/xxx-mks-kafka-cluster/1bdb7d3d-f9be-4d51-bc69-82e1c7a280eb-4
    Current Version :K1X6FK5RDHNB96
    cluster name: xxx-msk-mks-kafka-cluster
    Configuration ARN: arn:aws:kafka:ap-south-1:xxxx:configuration/xxx-mks-kafka-cluster/bcc660ab-ecba-4ac3-afa6-2c6013d6debf-4
    Configuration Revision: 1
    Kafka current version: 2.2.1
    ..................................................
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./update_kafka_version.py", line 71, in <module>
    update_kafka_version(name, targetKafkaVersion)
    File "./update_kafka_version.py", line 40, in update_kafka_version
    update_kafka_version_response = client.update_cluster_kafka_version(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateClusterKafkaVersion operation: The specified parameter value is identical to the current value for the cluster. Specify a different value, then try again.
    
    vaibhavkanchan@vkmacbook python-code % aws kafka describe-cluster --cluster-arn arn:aws:kafka:ap-south-1:xxxx:cluster/xxx-mks-kafka-cluster/1bdb7d3d-f9be-4d51-bc69-82e1c7a280eb-4 --query "ClusterInfo.CurrentVersion"
    "K1X6FK5RDHNB96"
    vaibhavkanchan@vkmacbook python-code %
```

As per from the boto3 documentation for kafka

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kafka.html#Kafka.Client.update_cluster_kafka_version

```
response = client.update_cluster_kafka_version(
    ClusterArn='string',
    ConfigurationInfo={
        'Arn': 'string',
        'Revision': 123
    },
    CurrentVersion='string',
    TargetKafkaVersion='string'
)
```

We have stored kafka zookeeper endpoints, bootstrap nodes, cluster arn and cluster version in parameter store and fetching the cluster arn from parameter store. We are fetching current version using describe-cluster but it's still giving error that the specified current version matches with the current cluster value.

python module for boto3 in my laptop

boto3 1.17.27
botocore 1.20.44

Any advise on fix this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Code is available in this link                                               
         https://github.com/vaibhavjpr/kafka-script/blob/master/update_kafka_version.py

Comment: The error suggests your current version already matches your target version, but you've mentioned no versions in your question to prove otherwise... Besides, this seems like a better question for AWS support if you think your code is correct

Comment: @OneCricketeer  .. The kafka version which we used is 2.2.1 and we were trying to upgrade it to 2.3.1.  I believe its giving error for CurrentVersion field.

Answer (score 0):

@Vaibhav, same error I see with MSK 2.7.0. When I try to delete topics, it was showing still topic with one partition so I added `delete.topic.enable=true` in cluster configuration and I try to update 3.3.1 but showing me error The `specified parameter value is identical to the current value for the cluster`

So I removed and try again and it worked. Might be that is default value and AWS does not allow to pass again same, it may work only with different value.